# Can't connect to local MySQL via TCP (Error 1045)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mysql5

`root@127.0.0.1` exists, but still can't connect to local MySQL. It looks like MySQL verifies hostname instead of lo ip(127.0.0.1).

```
root@castle /v/l/mysql# mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 5.6.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select user, host from user where user='root';
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | 127.0.0.1 |
| root | ::1       |
| root | castle    |
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
root@castle /v/l/mysql# mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'lixxx-yyy.members.linode.com' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is it getting "lixxx-yyy.members.linode.com" from?  Check you /etc/hosts file.

Try:

```
host 127.0.0.1
```

Expect to see:

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer localhost.
```

You can add that host to the hosts table to allow root to connect, or try to have "127.0.0.1" resolve to "localhost" as expected.

Comment: Yes, when I run `host 127.0.0.1`, I get '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer localhost. ' The problem is MySQL check my eth0 ip instead of lo ip.

Comment: `host 106.186.xxx.yyy`(eth0 ip):
yyy.xxx.186.106.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lixxx-yyy.members.linode.com.
`host 127.0.0.1`:
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer localhost.